# How do I create a native application using Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting started in C++. How can I setup Visual Studio 2008 to create native (not managed) code?

Comment: just for those that don't know it: native means normal c++ to the rest of us that don't use windows nomenclature, it doesn't imply a particular windows subsystem (such as posix/native/win32/console etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose a `Win32 Project`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting started you probably want a Win32 Console Application, and not a Win32 App. File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console Application

When you create the project itself you'll probably want to click Next before you click Finish, and select Empty Project so that VS won't add a bunch of junk to your project for you.

Answer (score 0):

File -> New -> project (maybe go to other lang if you see c#) -> visuall c++ -> win32

You can choose other types there it still be native.

(like mfc, but I doubt if you really need something other then the basic win32)

Comment: I think that the latest versions of MFC contain both native and managed code, better to check first if it is possible to stick to native code.

Comment: checked - it can be native.
I was a real mfc fan.. but after 5 years in c# I can't even think of going back...

Answer (score 0):

In the new projects dialog, choose any project type under the Visual C++ group. You'll need Visual Studio Pro, or Visual Studio Express for C++.