# It's possible to make a program in Visual Studio C++ 2008 that not use the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a native application using Visual C++ 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681264/how-do-i-create-a-native-application-using-visual-c-2008)

Can I develop a program that not use the .NET Framework (Win32) in Visual Studio C++? For example like the ones in Visual Studio C++ 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. File, New Project, go to Visual C++/Win32 in the tree, select one of the win32 project types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile native code with Visual C++, any version.

I don't know why you have written "(Win32)" after ".NET Framework", the Win32 API is not the .NET Framework.

Make sure you have "Common Language Runtime Support" set to "No" in your project options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make a new project of say "Win32 Project" type, rather than the CLR ones.